# AFrame: Updating an entity's a-animation with multiple attributes

Tags: aframe

Does anyone know how to update an animation to change multiple attributes? example: 3 buttons, all changing an a-animation's rotation. First button has a rotation animation of 30 0 0 to a box, second button has a rotation animation of 0 90 0 to the same box and third has 100 0 10 to the same box. Each button is calling the a-animation's id.

I 'activate' the first button's animation, however the other two don't.

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Answer (score 1):

You could have three separate animations that are triggered by different events:

```
<a-box id="box">
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="button1click"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="button2click"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="button3click"></a-animation>
</a-box>
```

Then here's a component to emit event on entities when clicked (copy and paste this code before your scene):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('emit-on-click', {
  schema: {
    target: {type: 'selector'},
    event: {type: 'string'}
  },

  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    var targetEl = this.data.target;
    var eventName = this.data.event;

    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      targetEl.emit(eventName);
    })
  }
});
```

Then attach the component to your buttons (whatever they are):

```
<a-entity id="button1" emit-on-click="target: #box; button1click"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="button2" emit-on-click="target: #box; button2click"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="button3" emit-on-click="target: #box; button3click"></a-entity>
```

When the buttons are clicked, the component we wrote will trigger an event on the box. The animations listen to that event and will play.

Also check out https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-animation-component